Automatically fetch, set and calculate mint price when minting NFTS
I need help with developing a minting dApp for testing. It's based of the Wagmi example. Whenever I try to mint NFTs, I am required to send the exact amount needed to pay for your NFT batch. I don't want that.
I want the user to just be able to mint, without having to calculate the amount to pay. Let them be shown the amount to pay in the transaction request that pops up.
For now, anytime I try to mint, the transcation reverts with the error Insufficient funds. How can I go about this?
import * as React from 'react'
import {
    type BaseError,
    useWaitForTransactionReceipt,
    useWriteContract
} from 'wagmi'
import { abi } from './abi/baba'

export default function MintNFT() {
    const {
        data: hash,
        error,
        isPending,
        writeContract
    } = useWriteContract()

    async function submit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement)
        const quantity = formData.get('quantity') as string
        writeContract({
            address: process.env.TEST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS',
          abi,
            functionName: 'Mint',
            args: [BigInt(quantity)],
        })
    }

    const { isLoading: isConfirming, isSuccess: isConfirmed } =
        useWaitForTransactionReceipt({
            hash,
        })

    return (
        <div className='mt-32 justify-center items-center flex'>
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <input name="quantity" placeholder="10" required />
                <button
                    disabled={isPending}
                    type="submit"
                >
                    {isPending ? 'Confirming...' : 'Mint'}
                </button>
                {hash && <div>Transaction Hash: {hash}</div>}
                {isConfirming && <div>Waiting for confirmation...</div>}
                {isConfirmed && <div>Transaction confirmed.</div>}
                {error && (
                    <div>Error: {(error as BaseError).shortMessage || error.message}</div>
                )}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

My contract code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;
    
import 'erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Pausable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol';

contract Baba is ERC721A, Ownable, Pausable, ReentrancyGuard {

    string private _baseTokenURI;
    uint256 public mintPrice;
    uint256 public maxSupply;
    uint256 public maxBatchSizePerAddress;
    uint256 public mintStart;

    constructor(address initialOwner) ERC721A("Baba", "BABA") Ownable(initialOwner) {}

    // Mint function
    function Mint(uint256 quantity) public payable whenNotPaused{
        require(mintStart != 0 && block.timestamp >= mintStart, "Mint has not yet started!");
        require(msg.value >= quantity * mintPrice, "Insufficient Funds");
        require(_numberMinted(msg.sender) + quantity <= maxBatchSizePerAddress, "You can't mint more than this!");
        require(_totalMinted() + quantity <= maxSupply, "All tokens sold out");
        _mint(msg.sender, quantity);
    }

    // OwnerMint
    function OwnerMint(uint256 quantity) public payable onlyOwner{
        require(_totalMinted() + quantity <= maxSupply, "All tokens sold out");
        _mint(msg.sender, quantity);
    }

    // Withdraw function
    function WithdrawFunds() external onlyOwner nonReentrant{
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        Address.sendValue(payable(msg.sender), balance);
    }

    // Metadata
    function setBaseURI(string calldata baseURI) external onlyOwner{
        _baseTokenURI = baseURI;
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _baseTokenURI;
    }

    function pause() external onlyOwner{
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() external onlyOwner{
        _unpause();
    }

    // Set mint date
    function setMintDate(uint256 _mintDate) external onlyOwner{
        mintStart = _mintDate; 
    }

    //Set mint price
    function setPrice(uint256 price_) external onlyOwner{
        mintPrice = price_;
    }

    // Setter functions for maxSupply and maxBatchSizePerAddress
    function setMaxSupply(uint256 _maxSupply) external onlyOwner {
        require(_totalMinted() <= _maxSupply, "New max supply cannot be less than already minted tokens");
        maxSupply = _maxSupply;
    }

    function setMaxBatchSizePerAddress(uint256 _maxBatchSizePerAddress) external onlyOwner {
        maxBatchSizePerAddress = _maxBatchSizePerAddress;
    }
}

Contract ABI can be found here
I thought that useReadContract would work, but I have no idea how to do it.
Thank you in advance.

Yes, you can use useReadContract hook by importing the same from wagmi, like:
import { 
  ... // other hooks, functions, etc.
  useReadContract 
} from 'wagmi'

Then, get the mintPrice from your contract in your MintNFT function component, like:
const { data: mintPrice } = useReadContract({
    abi,
    address: process.env.TEST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    functionName: "mintPrice"
})

And, finally multiplying the mintPrice with quantity to get the total price, and passing the resultant product in the value field of the writeContract function, like:
writeContract({
    address: process.env.TEST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    abi,
    functionName: 'Mint',
    args: [BigInt(quantity)],
    value: BigInt(mintPrice) * BigInt(quantity)
})

Your revised file would be:
import * as React from 'react'
import {
    type BaseError,
    useWaitForTransactionReceipt,
    useWriteContract,
    useReadContract
} from 'wagmi'

import { abi } from './abi/baba'

export default function MintNFT() {
    const {
        data: hash,
        error,
        isPending,
        writeContract
    } = useWriteContract()

    const { data: mintPrice } = useReadContract({
        abi,
        address: process.env.TEST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        functionName: "mintPrice"
    })

    async function submit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement)
        const quantity = formData.get('quantity') as string
        writeContract({
            address: process.env.TEST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
            abi,
            functionName: 'Mint',
            args: [BigInt(quantity)],
            value: BigInt(mintPrice) * BigInt(quantity)
        })
    }

    const { isLoading: isConfirming, isSuccess: isConfirmed } =
        useWaitForTransactionReceipt({
            hash,
        })

    return (
        <div className='mt-32 justify-center items-center flex'>
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <input name="quantity" placeholder="10" required />
                <button
                    disabled={isPending}
                    type="submit"
                >
                    {isPending ? 'Confirming...' : 'Mint'}
                </button>
                {hash && <div>Transaction Hash: {hash}</div>}
                {isConfirming && <div>Waiting for confirmation...</div>}
                {isConfirmed && <div>Transaction confirmed.</div>}
                {error && (
                    <div>Error: {(error as BaseError).shortMessage || error.message}</div>
                )}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}


It worked successfully. However, because it's TypeScript, there will be an error.
 writeContract({
  address: '0x7CE523E2B8730852BA62Aef9353b4B3c67891cC5',
  abi,
  functionName: 'Mint',
  args: [BigInt(quantity)],
  value: BigInt(mintPrice) * BigInt(quantity),  // There'll be an error here.
})

Error:
Argument of type 'bigint | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.ts(2345)
const mintPrice: bigint | undefined

The error manifests due to the possibility that mintPrice might be undefined when you try to use it in the writeContract function. To resolve this, you should ensure that mintPrice is defined before using it. You can add a check to handle the case when mintPrice is undefined.
To fix it, add this check:
 async function submit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) { 
    e.preventDefault() 
    const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement) 
    const quantity = formData.get('quantity') as string 

    // Ensure mintPrice is defined before calling the contract
    if (!mintPrice) {
      alert('Mint price is not available yet. Please wait.')
      return
    } //..rest of the code

So then, the revised code will be:
import * as React from 'react'
import { 
  type BaseError, 
  useWaitForTransactionReceipt, 
  useWriteContract,
  useReadContract 
} from 'wagmi'
import { abi } from './abi/baba'
 
export default function MintNFT() {
  const { data: mintPrice } = useReadContract({
    abi, 
    address: '0x7CE523E2B8730852BA62Aef9353b4B3c67891cC5',
    functionName: 'mintPrice',
  })

  const { 
    data: hash,
    error,   
    isPending, 
    writeContract 
  } = useWriteContract() 

  async function submit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) { 
    e.preventDefault() 
    const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement) 
    const quantity = formData.get('quantity') as string 

    // Ensure mintPrice is defined before calling the contract
    if (!mintPrice) {
      alert('Mint price is not available yet. Please wait.')
      return
    }

    writeContract({
      address: '0x7CE523E2B8730852BA62Aef9353b4B3c67891cC5',
      abi,
      functionName: 'Mint',
      args: [BigInt(quantity)],
      value: BigInt(mintPrice) * BigInt(quantity),  // mintPrice is guaranteed to be defined here
    })
  } 

  const { isLoading: isConfirming, isSuccess: isConfirmed } = 
    useWaitForTransactionReceipt({ 
      hash, 
    }) 

  return (
    <div className='mt-32 justify-center items-center flex'>
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <input name="quantity" placeholder="10" required />
      <button 
        disabled={isPending || !mintPrice}  // Disable the button if mintPrice is not loaded
        type="submit"
      >
        {isPending ? 'Confirming...' : 'Mint'} 
      </button>
      {hash && <div>Transaction Hash: {hash}</div>}
      {isConfirming && <div>Waiting for confirmation...</div>} 
      {isConfirmed && <div>Transaction confirmed.</div>} 
      {error && ( 
        <div>Error: {(error as BaseError).shortMessage || error.message}</div> 
      )} 
      {!mintPrice && <div>Loading mint price...</div>}  {/* Optional: Show loading state */}
    </form>
    </div>
  )
}

The mint will successfully work!
Thanks for the guide.
